# Eclipse and Java SDK

Tags: java, eclipse, sdk

I had previously download Eclipse and using it with Java 13.0.1
I change to Java's 13.0.2 version and delete the previous  ,but I got a message , trying to launch eclipse

**A Java Runtime environment (JRE) or Java Development Kit (JDK) must be available in order to run Eclipse. No Java virtual machine was found after searching the following locations:
C:/Program Files/Java/jdk-13.0.1/bin**

Comment: wich OS are you using ? linux or Windows you have to set environment variable path

Comment: See https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to run Eclipse with different Java version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469170/how-to-run-eclipse-with-different-java-version)