# Error installing PMD on Eclipse Version: 2020-06 (4.16.0)

Tags: eclipse-plugin, pmd, eclipse-2020-06, eclipse-pmd

I recently upgraded to Eclipse Version: 2020-06 (**4.16.0**) on Windows 10.

My java version is "14.0.1" 2020-04-14

After the upgrade, I attempted to install **Eclipse-PMD 2.0** from the Marketplace ( *help / Eclipse Marketplace / etc.* ) ...I receive the error(s):

> Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not
>   satisfiable   Software being installed: a.jre.javase 14.0.0   Software
>   being installed: Eclipse PMD Plug-in 2.0.0.202006052026
>   (ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.202006052026)
>   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: Eclipse PMD Plug-in 2.0.0.202006052026 (ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.202006052026)
>       To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.java.feature.feature.group
>   [2.0.0.202006052026,2.0.0.202006052026]   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: eclipse-pmd Java 2.0.0.202006052026 (ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.java 2.0.0.202006052026)
>       To: osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))   Cannot satisfy dependency:
>       From: eclipse-pmd Java Support (Optional, JDT Prerequisite) 2.0.0.202006052026 (ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.java.feature.feature.group 2.0.0.202006052026)
>       To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.java [2.0.0.202006052026,2.0.0.202006052026]

Does anyone have an idea(s) as regards the source of the issue ...if all else fails I may try building the PMD source from the github repo ( *https://github.com/eclipse-pmd/eclipse-pmd* ) but I cannot imagine why this should be necessary.

Comment: Looks like it really wants you to use Java 11.

Comment: Can you check that Eclipse is actually running with Java 14. I believe the log says it requires at least Java 11 (but 14 should be OK).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created eclipse-pmd and I can install eclipse-pmd 2.0 from the marketplace with Java 14 and Eclipse 2020-06 without any problems.

From the error message you provided it looks like there are two missing dependencies:

1. ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.java requires (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))
2. several plugins require org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu and ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.java

The first issue indicates that you do not run Eclipse with Java 11+. Check the Java version by opening the "Installation Details" dialog: `Help` > `About Eclipse IDE` > `Installation Details` > `Configuration`. Then look for the system property `java.version`. If it shows a version lower than 11, then you need to [configure Eclipse to run with Java 11+](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM).

The second issue looks like a subsequent error. Since ch.acanda.eclipse.pmd.java couldn't be installed, all plugins that depend on this plugin cannot be installed either. Why org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu is also mentioned in the error message is unclear to me since eclipse-pmd does not (directly) depend on this plugin and it should be a plugin installed by default in Eclipse.

If this does not fix your problem, then please open a [new issue](https://github.com/eclipse-pmd/eclipse-pmd/issues) on Github as it is easier to help with problems like this on Github than on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes ...when I installed the Eclipse 4.16 update, I was still on Java 8. Subsequent to the 4.16 update, I selected Java 14 ( i had 8, 9 , 11 and 14 installed on system but 8 was active when Eclipse was updated ) and tried again ...continued to have issues. Eventually, I uninstalled Eclipse and reinstalled from scratch ensuring that Java 11 was the selected JRE ...all went well ...Thanks for taking time to research this issue ...I appreciate the inputs

Answer (score 0):

You need to run Eclipse with a Java 11 JRE.  This is normally done by insuring you have JAVA_HOME set to Java 11, and JAVA_HOME in your path.   Alternatively, you can modify eclipse.ini and specify Java 11 as the vm ([How to run Eclipse with different Java version?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18469170/how-to-run-eclipse-with-different-java-version)).