# Error Installing DevStyle plugin for Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-cdt

I installed the current latest version of eclipse (202006) CDT.  I have tried installing the DevStyle plugin and received the following error:

```
Cannot complete the install because some dependencies are not satisfiable
  Software being installed: a.jre.javase 14.0.0
  Software currently installed: C/C++ Autotools support 9.11.1.202004012023 (org.eclipse.cdt.autotools.feature.group 9.11.1.202004012023)
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: C/C++ Autotools support 9.11.1.202004012023 (org.eclipse.cdt.autotools.feature.group 9.11.1.202004012023)
    To: org.eclipse.equinox.p2.iu; org.eclipse.tools.templates.freemarker.java11 [1.1.100.202001140305,1.1.100.202001140305]
  Cannot satisfy dependency:
    From: Template Engine Freemarker Support (Java 11) 1.1.100.202001140305 (org.eclipse.tools.templates.freemarker.java11 1.1.100.202001140305)
    To: osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))
```

This error message is fairly cryptic to me. I looked a similar problem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62439118/error-installing-pmd-on-eclipse-version-2020-06-4-16-0). But this specifies Java 11 and Java 14.  I don't know how this relates to my JRE 1.8.0_251 (Version 8 Update 251).  I also don't understand the new scheme for Java. Does Oracle not release JRE's anymore?

I don't need to program in Java. I only need runtime environment to run eclipse, so I don't want/need full JDK (especially since this seems to require some licensing/commercial aspects). I also believe I will get similar errors with other plugins that I intend to install.

So two questions here:

1. Is there a way to get JRE's for Java 11 or Java 14?
2. What version of JRE/JDK do I need to get this to work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
To: osgi.ee; (&(osgi.ee=JavaSE)(version=11))
```

This means that at least Java 11 is required by this code. It will not run with Java 8. You will have to move to a newer Java.

Newer versions of Java only have a JDK with no separate JRE. The Java builds on the [OpenJDK](https://openjdk.java.net/) site have a 'normal' free license and are essentially to same as the Oracle Java.

Answer (score 7):

It's actually a bug, Java 11 is not required for CDT 9.11. You can take a look here to use a workaround: [cdt dev mailing list Java 11 problem](https://www.eclipse.org/lists/cdt-dev/msg34492.html)

Comment: From the mailing list I saw this: "Java 11 is not required to *run* CDT 9.11.1, but is required if using Eclipse 2020-06 and you want to do most installation operations"  Since I'm using eclipse202006, and I'm installing other plugins, I believe I still needed Java 11 or higher.

Comment: Yep, but only for installation, so if you disable the check everything will work as expected